Secret not defined error in nextjs project
After creating a nextjs project with create create-next-app, I ran it like npm run dev. Got "Error: secret is not defined". I created the .env.local file in the main dir and added SECRET=________. Restarted the run many times.
But the error's still there, any idea why?

are you sure you are targeting the right directory in the terminal?
